# Window still calling method after being closed

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all I don't know if this is a dumb question. I have this scenario, first I have a main window

```
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    //dt is a System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer variable
    dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 30000);
    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshData);

    dt.Start();

}
```

the refreshData method does this:

```
public void refreshData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Conection c = new Conection();
            //this method just returns 'hello' doesn't affect my problem
    c.sayHello();
}
```

This main window also has a button, when I click on the button I call to another class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowData d = new ShowData();
    d.Show();
}
```

This class is pretty much similar to the main window, it has an own DispatcherTimer too

```
public ShowData()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 30000);
    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshData);

    dt.Start();
}

public void refreshData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Conection c = new Conection();
    c.sayHello();
}
```

I track the calls to sayHello with the visual studio debugger, the problem is when I close the 'ShowData' window, the call to sayHello from the ShowData class is still appearing

Am I not closing the window properly? how can I stop the calls after closing the window?

PS: I tried setting the DispatcherTimer to null in on_closing event

Comment: Did you try stopping it?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.stop.aspx

Comment: @AustinSalonen I don't! I've tried and works, man I knew it was a silly thing... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the DispatcherTimer using the `Stop()` method on your window `OnWindowClosing` event.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
   DispatcherTimer MyTimer;

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      MyTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
      MyTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 30000);
      MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshData);
      // Start the timer
      MyTimer.Start();
   }

   public void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
   {
       // stop the timer
       MyTimer.Stop();
   }

   public void refreshData(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Conection c = new Conection();
      c.sayHello();
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, weird though, for me a window is completely destroyed after being closed

Comment: yes, but the dispatchtimer is a new thread. not the ui thread in which the windows lives