# WPF application to display images on three or more windows. This application cashes due to memory leakage issue(Details in code comments)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

/*I am developing WPF application to display images (fetched from database) on three or more windows. Every window displays image(s) for 20 seconds and opens next window before closing itself. My application crashes due to memory leakage. I found the objects of every window are not cleared by GC, rather pile-up in memory until application is closed/crashed.*/

```
//________________MainWindow_______________//

using System;
using System.Windows;
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Memory_Leakage
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       int d = 0;

       public MainWindow()
       {

           InitializeComponent();


           Dispatcher_timer();

       }

       public void Dispatcher_timer()
       {

           var activeTimer = new DispatcherTimer
           {
               Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
           };
           activeTimer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

               Clock clock = new Clock();
               clock.Show();

           };
           activeTimer.Start();

       }
   }
}


//_________________Window2_________________//

using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Memory_Leakage
{
   public partial class Clock : Window
   {
       long d = 0;
       public Clock()
       {

           InitializeComponent();

           DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
           timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
           timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
           timer.Start();

           clocklbl.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToUpper();     
           datelbl.Content = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").ToUpper();

           void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

               clocklbl.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToUpper();       

               if (++d == 20)
               {

                   Imp_Note imp_Note = new Imp_Note();
                   imp_Note.ShowDialog();

                   this.Close();


               }
           }
       }
   }
}


//_________________Window2_________________//

using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Memory_Leakage
{
   ///<summary>
   /// Interaction logic for Imp_Note.xaml
   ///</summary>

public partial class Imp_Note : Window
   {

       long d = 0;

       public Imp_Note()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
           timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
           timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
           timer.Start();

           void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

               if (++d == 20)
               {

                   this.Close();

               }

           }

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: Dispose the timers, dispose the images.

Comment: I don't see any database calls...

Comment: @CodeCaster Neither DispatcherTimer nor Image/ImageSource is IDisposable.

Comment: @Clemens whoops, look at me typing comments as if everyone is still on WinForms. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510523/unreferenced-active-dispatchertimer-and-garbage-collector though.

Comment: What about stopping the timer on closing the windows?

Comment: The timers stay active, preventing the windows from getting garbage-collected.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534583/window-still-calling-method-after-being-closed

Comment: Stopping timers worked for me. Thank you all.

Comment: You could use ’timer.Stop();‘ in your code. You can answer it by yourself ad accept it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)